# Update MySql PHP Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am programming an App and I have a problem now. 
I want to Update the data from my datanse with a Update button. 
For that I am using PHP and MySQL. I always get the error `...on a null objekt reference`. I will post my PHP and Java Code. I hope you can help me.

update.php

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['etName']) &&  isset($_POST['etSurname'])
    && isset($_POST['etStreet']) && isset($_POST['etCity'])){

    if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == "Update"){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $Name = $_POST['etName'];
        $Surname = $_POST['etSurname'];
        $Street= $_POST['etStreet'];
        $City = $_POST['etCity'];


        include_once("dbConnect.php");
        $sql = "UPDATE T_Student SET Name = '$Name', Surname = '$Surname', Street = $Street, City = '$City'
                WHERE ID_Student = $id";

        mysqli_query($sql);

    }
    else if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == "Delete"){
        include_once("dbConnect.php");
        $pro_id = $_GET['id'];
        mysqli_query("DELETE FROM T_Student WHERE ID_Student = $id");
        echo "Data Deleted.";

    }
}
else{
    $id = "";
    $Name = "";
    $Surname = "";
    $Street = "";
    $City = "";

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $Name = $_GET['id'];
        include_once("dbConnect.php");

        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT Name, Surname, Street, City
                FROM T_Student WHERE ID_Student= $Name");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id = $row['ID_Student'];
        $Name = $row['Name'];
        $Surrname = $row['Surname'];
        $Street = $row['Street'];
        $City = $row['City'];

    }
    else{
        echo "No Data to Edit";
    }
}
?>
```

info.java

```
 String updateTrigger = "";

    @Override
    public void onClick(View sender) {

            UpdateData taskUpdate = new UpdateData();
            updateTrigger = "Update";
            taskUpdate.execute(new String[]{"MY HTTP ADRESS?id="+ ID_Student});
            InfoFragment fragment = new InfoFragment ();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    private class UpdateData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        private String error;

        String text = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Editting Data...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        InputStream is1;
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            for(String url: urls){
                try {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("btnUpdate", updateTrigger));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtName", etName.getText().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtSurname", etSurname.getText().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtStreet", etStreet.getText().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtCity", etCity.getText().toString()));

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    is1 = response.getEntity().getContent();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    error = "ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage();
                    return false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    error = "ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if(result == false){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                if(is1 == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sending Wrong Parameters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Edit Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); <----- THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR APPEARS

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your error? post your logcat

Comment: show the information about your error NullPointerException. post the whole logcat

Comment: where are the error ?